# My query works uncorrectly

Tags: android, sqlite

My application works with sql lite database I wrotte query in SQlite developer and test it, that was working correctly but when I wrote this at android, it returns only one value insteed of several. whats wrong with android query?

code of procedure

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    m._id,
    m.name,
    m.the_best_time,
    m.the_worse_time,
    count(p._id) as qPoints
FROM sickness AS s
INNER JOIN list_of_sicknesses AS l
    ON s._id = l.sickness_id
INNER JOIN point AS p
    ON p.sickness_list = l.number
INNER JOIN meridian AS m
    ON m._id = p.meridian_id
WHERE s.sick = 'value'
GROUP BY
    m.name,
    m.the_best_time,
    m.the_worse_time,m._id
```

code of android query

```
 String query="select distinct m." +MeridianDB.ID+
            ",m."+MeridianDB.NAME+",m."+MeridianDB.BEST_TIME+
            ",m."+MeridianDB.WORSE_TIME+",count(p."+PointDB.ID+") as         qPoints from "+
            SicknessDB.TABLE_NAME+" as s inner join "+ListOFSicknessDB.TABLE_NAME+
            " as l on s."+SicknessDB.ID+" = l."+ListOFSicknessDB.SICKNESS_ID+
            " inner join "+PointDB.TABLE_NAME+" as p on p."+PointDB.SICKNESS_LIST+
            " = l."+ListOFSicknessDB.NUMBER+" inner join "+MeridianDB.TABLE_NAME+
            " as m on m."+MeridianDB.ID+" = p."+PointDB.MERIDIAN_ID+" where s."+
            SicknessDB.NAME+"=? group by m."+MeridianDB.ID+",m."+MeridianDB.NAME+
            ",m."+MeridianDB.BEST_TIME+",m."+MeridianDB.WORSE_TIME;
```

Comment: Did you verify whether the actual query in the android code matches the sqlite query that you mention above?

Comment: they are same except "where s."+ SicknessDB.NAME+"=?

Comment: not really. android query lacks last GROUP BY `m._id`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `DISTINCT` clause (because you're already using `GROUP BY`)
I'm not sure that issue is in this part, but having `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in one query at the same time is usually not the best practice

Comment: I tryed to do that nothing changed